# fullcalendar addDay not working

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

So when I add an event that is not an allDay event it seems to still set it as an allDay event.

JSON code

```
[{"id":"1","agent_id":"1","customer_id":"0","title":"Doctors","text":"This is a test calendar","start":"2012-01-12 10:20:00","end":"2012-01-12 11:00:00","allDay":"false"}]
```

I am using the following to load the json

```
eventSources: [

                                // your event source
                                {
                                    url: 'system/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/json-events.php',
                                    type: 'POST',

                                  error: function() {
                                        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                                    },
                                    //color: 'Light-Blue',   // a non-ajax option
                                    textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
                                },

                                {
                                    url: 'system/classes/core.php?task=calendar&q=fetch&userid='+userid,
                                    type: 'POST',

                                  error: function() {
                                        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                                    },
                                    color: 'orange',   // a non-ajax option
                                    textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
                                }

                            // any other sources...

                        ],
```

My question is how to get the events that should not be an allday event to show as time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have quotes around the boolean for allDay. The [docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) say: Don't include quotes around your true/false. This value is not a string!

Either have your json return:

```
"allDay": false
```

or you could remove that from the json and set the [allDayDefault](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/) property for the source:

```
eventSources: [

   // your event source
   {
     url: 'system/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/json-events.php',
     type: 'POST',
     allDayDefault: false,
     error: function() {
                         alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                        },
     //color: 'Light-Blue',   // a non-ajax option
     textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
    },
```