# jQuery FullCalendar not parsing json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, fullcalendar

My FullCalendar jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    events: {
        url: '/admin/index.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            m: '1',
            e: 'fetchCalEvents'
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',
        textColor: 'black'
    }

});
```

If I hit the test url:

```
http://localhost/admin/index.php?m=1&e=fetchCalEvents
```

I get good looking JSON:

```
[{"id":"13","title":"Test Entry","start":"2013-04-20 04:20:00","end":"2013-04-20 05:20:00","url":"#","allDay":false}]
```

But aggravatingly the calendar pops up only:

```
There was an error while fetching events!
```

Which doesn't tell me much.  Is there some way to get better error handling on this plugin?  I didn't see anything in the docs.  Any idea what is wrong?

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was directing the ajax call in through a controller.  The plugin started working when I gutted my controller code for the calendar and put it in a standalone script in the same directory as the calendar was loading.  :/  Far from ideal, but I'm in a hurry.  :( :(

Answer (score 0):

try with this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814715/fullcalendar-addday-not-working)

see the doc official maybe find  reply your question